# Set page title without using deprecated <action>

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, xml, page-title

Every answer I can find for setting the page title (H1 tag not the tab title) uses this format:

```
<action method="setPageTitle">
    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Title goes here</argument>
</action>
```

As the [action tag has been deprecated](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html) I don't want to use this.

When I try the below method it is ignored.

```
<arguments>
    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Title goes here</argument>
</arguments>
```

**How do I achieve the same result using `<arguments>`?**

Does Magento really force us to use deprecated tags to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The  directive is marked as deprecated because Magento wants to stop using imperative directives (xml order what to do) and switch to using declarative (xml declare value but it's up to program to use it) layout directives instead.

This parameter is called  "Content Heading" and is set in

```
AdminOffice->Content->Elements->Pages->Action->Edit->Content->ContentHeading
```

And PHTML

```
/var/www/html/m/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml
```

get it like this

```
escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading())
```

out of PHP class

```
/var/www/html/m/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml
```

Since Magento uses declarative layout directives there is no way to force PHP to use xml argument.

```
---------------------------------------------------
Example how to impose xml attribute
```

in

```
AdminOffice->Content->Elements->Pages->Action->Edit->Design->Layout Update XML
```

copy/past

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Title goes here</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

in (don't just overwrite original file, extend it in your theme)

```
/var/www/html/m/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml
```

update variable `$title` to use our XML value

```
$blockTitle = $this->getTitle();
if ($blockTitle){
    $title = $blockTitle;
}
```

Save and clean cache